# Responsive Design works in Firefox, failure in Chrome

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a list such like below, in Firefox the images actually scale along with the browser width, but in Chrome when I resize the images stay the same size and the `<li>` sections just fill with white space. [See what I mean here](http://cl.ly/Jz8A)

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
li img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 307px) and (max-width: 440px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 440px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 612px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 612px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 33.3333%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 901px){
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 33.3333%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width: 1079px){
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 20%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1079px) and (max-width: 1224px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 20%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) and (max-width: 1530px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 20%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1530px) and (max-width : 1824px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 16.6666%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {
    li{
        float:left;
        width: 11.1111%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
    li img{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {    
    li img{
        max-width: 100%;
    }    
}
```

turns out I needed to add max-width add gave in to conditional browser hacking for firefox and chrome